# how to run npm webpack in mvn release:perform goal

Tags: maven, jenkins, npm

I am trying to create  RC versions for the application, I have mvn release:prepare ,release:perform  goals to create RC . Sequence of event on Jenkins server are like . 
npm install 
 npm run build (to execute webpack)
 mvn release:prepare  - it generates correct RC with webpack exceuted files .
 mvn release:perform - it create RC in checkout folder but webpack executed files are missing  .

Any help is much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve my self ... 
I have updated maven release plugin to execute  custom profile, under configuration added following profile to execute npm goals.
npm

custom profile is created with below plugin then execute npm commands and it worked as expected .
                exec-maven-plugin                  org.codehaus.mojo

Comment: Could you provide an example of your pom config? I'd like to run npm install followed by an npm run command before my war file is generated.

Comment: Create profile  in pom to just run NPM cmd , and use plugin  exec-maven-plugin and  use like this  <execution><id>npm install </id><goals><goal>exec</goal></goals><phase>initialize</phase<configuration><executable>npm</executable><arguments><argument>install</argument></arguments><workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory></configuration></execution> .........  now use this profile in maven release plugin  - <releaseProfiles>release-npm prifle</releaseProfiles>